# Cassandra gets stuck on Initializing IndexInfo

Tags: java, cassandra, centos, nodetool

I'm using Cassandra on a CentOS machine. After it failed some time ago, I restarted it via
`sudo service cassandra restart`
and started getting Connection refused error all over the place - I couldn't even run `nodetool status` without running into that issue.

After some digging and subsequent restarts, I noticed in the `debug.log` that the startup sequence gets stuck at the following:

`INFO  [main] 2018-04-03 09:40:15,156 ColumnFamilyStore.java:389 - Initializing system.IndexInfo
INFO  [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-04-03 09:40:15,851 BufferPool.java:226 - Global buffer pool is enabled, when pool is exahusted (max is 512 mb) it will allocate on heap
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2018-04-03 09:40:15,873 SSTableReader.java:479 - Opening <path>/IndexInfo-9f5c6374d48532299a0a5094af9ad1e3/mc-300-big (58 bytes)
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:2] 2018-04-03 09:40:15,873 SSTableReader.java:479 - Opening <path>3/system/IndexInfo-9f5c6374d48532299a0a5094af9ad1e3/mc-301-big (59 bytes)
DEBUG [SSTableBatchOpen:3] 2018-04-03 09:40:15,873 SSTableReader.java:479 - Opening <path>/IndexInfo-9f5c6374d48532299a0a5094af9ad1e3/mc-299-big (302 bytes)`

Opening these files should take about a second - it's stuck on it for ages (as in, it never moved beyond this point). I suspect that some of the files involved must be corrupted (although I'm surprised the Java doesn't catch some sort of an exception here).

What should I do? If I delete these folders, would that result in me losing data? What other diagnostics can I run to establish the source of the problem? For the record, any sort of `nodetool` command exits with a "Connection Refused" error.

Version numbers:
Cassandra: 3.0.9
Java: 1.8.0_162
CentOS: 6.9

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was in the files involved becoming corrupted - running `touch` on all the files in the data folder (`Data, CompressionInfo, Index`, etc.) and erasing the post-crash commitlogs allowed the Cassandra to get up. A few hundred datarows were lost (probably due to me deleting the commitlogs), but at least the database is back up!